# Load for Xen units

Tags: vps, xen, solusvm

I'm looking for a way to check load for Xen units on a xen Node run by Solusvm. I know OpenVZ can show container load in the solusvm panel. But if I go to load in svm for the Xen Node the load page is empty.

There is xentop, the problem is that only shows cpu usage and ram. Load is a mix of many factors, cpu, io, ram, etc. So is there a way to actually see per container load?

Answer (score 0):

To see true load inside the containers, you'll need an agent running inside the containers that can inspect process details that Dom0 tools don't have easy access to.

Pick a monitoring tool of your choosing and use that to monitor both your host and your guests.